# accepting ether in smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, ether

I'm trying to create a simple smart contract to learn solidity and how ethereum works.

From what I understand, using the modify payable on a method will make it accept a value. We then deduct from the sender and add that somewhere else, in this code I'm trying to send it to the owner of the contract.

```
contract  AcceptEth {
    address public owner;
    uint public bal;
    uint public price;
    mapping (address => uint) balance;

    function AcceptEth() {
        // set owner as the address of the one who created the contract
        owner = msg.sender;
        // set the price to 2 ether
        price = 2 ether;
    }

    function accept() payable returns(bool success) {
        // deduct 2 ether from the one person who executed the contract
        balance[msg.sender] -= price;
        // send 2 ether to the owner of this contract
        balance[owner] += price;
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I interact with this contract through remix, I get an error of "VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas" it creates a transaction and the gas price was 21000000000 and the value was 0.00 ETH when I'm trying to get 2 ether from anyone who executes this method.

What's wrong with the code? Alternatively I can add a a variable for one to input the value they want to send, along with a withdraw method, right? but for the sake of learning, I wanted to keep it simple. but even this code feels a bit simple and feels like something is missing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think where you're getting lost is that contracts have built in mechanisms for receiving and holding ether. For example, if you wanted to make it so your `accept()` method receives exactly 2 ether (or whatever you set `price` to), you would do something like this:

```
contract  AcceptEth {
    address public owner;
    uint public price;
    mapping (address => uint) balance;

    function AcceptEth() {
        // set owner as the address of the one who created the contract
        owner = msg.sender;
        // set the price to 2 ether
        price = 2 ether;
    }

    function accept() payable {
        // Error out if anything other than 2 ether is sent
        require(msg.value == price);

        // Track that calling account deposited ether
        balance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
}
```

Now, say you have two accounts with the following balances:

> 0x01 = 50 ether
>
> 0x02 = 20 ether

And this contract is deployed and has the address of 0xc0. All addresses can hold ether, so even the contract itself has a balance. Since it was just deployed (and wasn't deployed with any initial ether), it's balance is 0.

Now say 0x01 calls `accept()` sending in 2 ether. The transaction will execute and the 3 addresses in our example will have the following balances:

> 0x01 = 48 ether
>
> 0x02 = 20 ether
>
> 0xc0 = 2 ether

Now, say 0x02 calls `accept()` TWICE, passing 2 ether both times:

> 0x01 = 48 ether
>
> 0x02 = 16 ether
>
> 0xc0 = 6 ether

The contract holds all of the ether sent to it. But, your contract also holds state (the `balance` map which you defined in code) which is tracking who deposited what. So, you know from that mapping that 0x01 deposited 2 ether and 0x02 deposited 4 ether. If you wanted to introduce a `refund()` method that sends the ether back, you would write it like this

```
function refund(uint amountRequested) public {
  require(amountRequested > 0 && amountRequested <= balance[msg.sender]);

  balance[msg.sender] -= amountRequested;

  msg.sender.transfer(amountRequested); // contract transfers ether to msg.sender's address
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this really helped understand it all better. 

how and where can I find the right tutorial to go about creating a withdrawal / transfer of the contract's funds to and limited to just the contract owner's address?

Comment: when I interact with this in remix, there's no field to specify a value when executing the accept method?

Comment: The Solidity documentation has it all. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Comment: Run tab, top right. Value field. Drop down let’s you specify which type to send (ether, wei, etc)

Comment: How to store balance so that it can be converted into real Ether at production level?